# Can not delete file in emu 8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

```
 .model small

.data

filename db "name.txt",0     
err db "error$"
.code          

start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
;;file is opening
mov ah,3dh
lea dx,filename
mov al,0
int 21h

jc err1
;delete the file not working
 mov ah, 41h
lea dx,filename
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h

err1: lea dx,err
mov ah,09h
int 21h

end start
```

I am trying to delete the file from the directory , but the code is not working , i can open and read the file but cant delete the file. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: What kind of file system is it on?  Do you have the correct permissions for the file?

Comment: Trying to delete an open file might not work, especially since you opened it using "exclusive" mode. Also, what's the error code you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your operating system doesn't allow to delete an open file, try close it:

```
HANDLER DW ?        ;◄■■ VARIABLE IN DATA SEGMENT.
...
;;file is opening
mov ah,3dh
lea dx,filename
mov al,0
int 21h     
jc err1
MOV HANDLER, AX ;◄■■ PRESERVE FILE HANDLER.

;CLOSE FILE.
MOV AH, 3EH     ;◄■■
MOV BX, HANDLER ;◄■■ HANDLER OF FILE TO CLOSE.
INT 21H

;delete the file NOW IS working
 mov ah, 41h
lea dx,filename
int 21h
```

Comment: You mean *handle* (as in "file handle"), not *handler*.

Comment: @PeterCordes, oops, latino english :)